# PHP json foreach returning only last record

Tags: php, mysql, json, foreach

Helo, i am having a problem with my json, i am having a foreach in a foreach in a for... dont ask why

My problem is that the foreach  `foreach( $result2 as $rowx )` only returns the last record. the query is ok is working fine it returns 2 fields from database , but only the last is echo'ed.

Any help please.

```
 if(!$location){
    echo '{"locations":[';
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM locations"); 
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query -> fetchAll();
    $num_rows = count($result);
           for ($x = 1; $x < $num_rows; $x++) {
    foreach( $result as $row ) { 
    $qer = "SELECT DISTINCT t.id_temp,f.id_fridge,l.id_location,t.id_sensor,f.denumire AS 'fridge_name',l.name AS 'location_name',l.address AS 'location_address',t.date,t.time,t.temp FROM fridges AS f,locations AS l,temperature AS t WHERE f.fk_location=l.id_location AND f.fk_id_sensor=t.id_sensor AND l.id_location='1' AND t.date='07/05/2015' ORDER BY t.id_temp DESC LIMIT 0,2";

    $query2 = $db->prepare($qer); 
    $query2->execute();
    $result2 = $query2 -> fetchAll();



    echo '{"location_name":"'.$row[1].'","nr_fridges":'.$row[2].',"fridge":';
    foreach( $result2 as $rowx ) { 

    }
    echo '{
    '.$rowx['fridge_name'].'

    }'; 

    echo '}';

    }
        echo "]}";
    exit; 
    }
    }
```

Comment: Check at json_encode function, it will make debug really easier because in this way, it is really hardly readable

Comment: What's the purpose of empty foreach (most inner one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `echo`es outside the loop.

```
foreach( $result2 as $rowx ) { 
    echo '{
        '.$rowx['fridge_name'].'
    }'; 

    echo '}';
}

echo "]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably caused by the fact that you are using `$rowx['fridge_name']` *after* the loop instead of inside it:

```
foreach( $result2 as $rowx ) { 

}
echo '{
'.$rowx['fridge_name'].'

}';
```

should be:

```
foreach( $result2 as $rowx ) { 
  echo '{
  '.$rowx['fridge_name'].'
  }'; 
}
```

Also note that now you are not building valid json as an object would need a key - value pair where string values are quoted in double quotes `"`.

However, you should not build json manually anyway, instead you should build an array of the form you need and at the very end you do:

```
echo json_encode($your_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $result2 as $rowx ) { //foreach begin

    } //foreach end
```

your `echo` is outside the `foreach` loop.

Try this,

```
foreach( $result2 as $rowx ) { 
    echo '{
    '.$rowx['fridge_name'].'
    }';
}
```